# How can I access API Gateway model from within Lambda function?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have a Lambda function mapped to API Gateway, where I have [defined models](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/models-mappings.html) for the request input and response output.

Is there any way to access those API models from within the Lambda function?

I know actual request data can be passed from the API Gateway to the Lambda using body mapping templates and accessing that request data from the event object. What I am specifically looking for is access to the model (stored in API Gateway) within the Lambda code itself? Is this possible?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly ... your Lambda code is an AWS client. Any AWS client, with appropriate permissions, can make API calls to AWS to retrieve information about AWS resources. So, your Lambda code can, for example, call API Gateway SDK getModel() to describe an existing API Gateway model.

Comment: @cyorkston Are you asking about retrieving model metadata or how to make API calls on a model in api gateway such as /hotels or /cars ?

Comment: I am trying to get the model schema into a lambda function. It appears the only option is to call the Amazon API Gateway REST API in order to get this.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot access model within Lambda function. The whole purpose of the model is to validate your data before it hit Lambda function. Lambda will only get the actual data you are sending from API gateway and Lambda is not aware about your API gateway model at all